# How to retrieve data from Firebase and assign to a string in strings.xml in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I have a data in Firebase like:

```
-Moon1
   sm_1 : "Titan" 
-Moon2
   sm_2 : "Europa"
-Moon3
   sm_3 : "Triton"
-Moon4
   sm_4 : "Io"
```

My `strings.xml` file is like below

```
<string name="sm_1">/*Data from firebase*/</string>
<string name="sm_2">/*Data from firebase*/</string>
<string name="sm_3">/*Data from firebase*/</string>
<string name="sm_4">/*Data from firebase*/</string>
```

I want the string `sm_1` to have the data `Titan`, `sm_2` = `Europa` and likewise. I am able to retrieve the data from Firebase and assign to a `Listview`.

But how to assign to a string in `strings.xml`?

Comment: Please provide the code of whatever you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure you cannot create string resources on runtime as they are compiled into your apk when you are bundling your project. What you are thinking is persisting your data from Firebase, which can be done in many ways.

You could save your [instance state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states), create a [Room database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), a [SQL database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite), use [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) even. However since you already seem to have a Firebase database set up maybe use that always.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible by following codes but however, this ain't a good practice at run time. Instead, try saving `strings` ***in a variable*** then setting your data to `adapter` or etc.

In your `Strings.xml`:

```
<string name="sm_1">%1$s</string>
```

In `Java`-`Kotlin` side:

```
val yourString = "Titan" // Or you can set this from FireBase output
val formatted = getString(R.string.my_xml_string, yourString)
```